# LaTeXTools for Sublime Text 2 automatically changes Build System Settings

Tags: sublime-text, build-system

I have been using sublime text 2 with LaTexTools to write my latex files the last 3 years without any issues.

Now all of a sudden everytime I build my .tex file, the 'Build System' setting in my editor is automatically set to 'LaTeX' eveytime I build a .tex document.

This is extremly annoying as I have to manually change the setting back to automatic to build other files, such as Python scripts. As I often like to write reports while doing work, this is unbearable.

Before having the Build System on automatic meant I could jump back and forth between .tex files and scripts. I didn't change any settings (that I know of) to cause this change in behavior, it just happened overnight.

Is there any way to revert to the old behavior here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure this is really on topic for this site, as it seems more of a specific problem with Sublime Text.

Comment: You might be right @egreg, I just saw other quite specific questions about SublimeText and LaTeXTools on here, so figured I would give it a shot. I will delete my question if there are no responses in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest LaTeXTools version `v3.12.0` introduced a quickpanel to select between different build configurations with `ctrl+shift+b`. To to this it also overwrites the build key `ctrl+b` in LaTeX files to select a build system in ST2, because it does not support build variants by default. Unfortunately the build system is Window wide and it interferes with your other files. You can overwrite it by adding this keybinding to your keymap:

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+b"],
    "command": "build",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex" }
    ]
},
```

Comment: This fixed the issue @r-stein, thank you for your assistance.